# How to optimize successive numpy dot products?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, data-science, linear-algebra

The bottleneck of some code I have is:

```
for _ in range(n):
    W = np.dot(A, W)
```

where n can vary, A is a fixed size MxM matrix, W is Mx1.

Is there a good way to optimize this?

Answer (score 3):

#### Numpy Solution

Since `np.dot` is just a matrix multiplication for your shapes you can write what you want as `A^n*W`. With ^ being repeated matrix multiplication "matrix_power" and * matrix multiplication. So you can rewrite your code as

```
np.linalg.matrix_power(A,n)@W
```

#### Linear Algebra Solution

You can do even better with linear algebra. Assuming for the moment `W` was an eigenvector of `A` i.e. that `A*W=a*W` with a just a number then it follows `A^n*W=a^n*W.` And now you might think ok but what if `W` is not an eigenvector. Since matrix multiplication is linear it is just as good if `W` can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors and there is even a generalisation of this idea in case `W` can not be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors. If you want to read more about this google *diagonalization* and *Jordan normal form*.

Comment: If A is diagonalizable as A = P D P^-1, then A^n W = P D^n P^-1 W and P^-1 W can be precomputed.

Comment: `matrix_power` improves on the raw `A@A@A...` by grouping the multiplications as much as possible, `A2=A@A`, `A4=A2@A2` etc.

Comment: Thanks, definitely a nicer way to write this. I will say I found it substantially slower not faster in practice, but it's given me the idea of pre-computing all the powers of A that I need, which should be faster.

Comment: @YvesDaoust That's also a valid way to think about it, note that what I write under "Linear Algebra Solution" is basically the same though.

Comment: @LukasS: I didn't say there is any difference. I just gave details.

Comment: @azural: there must be a misunderstanding. The linear algebra method *cannot* be slower (unless you count preprocessing and the exponents are tiny).

Comment: @YvesDaoust it's slower in my domain and in a toy program I created to try with other ranges of values, e.g. with a low n of 4 or a high n of 100. I imagine it's all down to implementation details in numpy.

Comment: @azural: this is quite abnormal.